# Elegant and code saving way to count an attribute from a loop without using "If...Else Statements"

Tags: python, performance, optimization

I have a file in *.las format and i wish to count how many points are Return1, Return2,...,Return5
I use a If...Else Statements, but i wish to understand if there is a way more elegant and code saving. Thanks in advance for help and tips.

```
    Return1 = 0
    Return2 = 0
    Return3 = 0
    Return4 = 0
    Return5 = 0
    count = 0
    for p in lasfile.File(inFile,None,'r'):
        count +=1
        if p.return_number == 1:
            Return1 += 1
        elif p.return_number == 2:
            Return2 += 1
        elif p.return_number == 3:
            Return3 += 1
        elif p.return_number == 4:
            Return4 += 1
        elif p.return_number == 5:
            Return5 += 1
```

Comment: Perhaps you should use a dictionary to store your "returnX"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `dict` of counters (in this case it can also be a list). [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is quite convenient:

```
from collections import defaultdict
returns = defaultdict(int)
count = 0
for p in lasfile.File(inFile, None, 'r'):
    count += 1
    returns[p.return_number] += 1
```

**Edit:** I'm not sure if DSM is posting a separate answer with [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) examples, so I'm going to reply to the OP's question here:

> @DSM: could i combine Counter? ex: if i wish to count p.return_number and p.scan_angle in the same time – Gianni

`Counter` will count values in the iterable you give it. The iterable is supposed to be homogenic. For example, if `scan_angle`s can take values of `1`, `2`, etc., then you can't use the same `Counter` for both and get correct results. If the values don't overlap, you can get correct results, but your code will be confusing and hard to understand. I'd suggest to use two `Counter`'s: one for `return_number`s and one for `scan_angle`'s. You can use the same loop to populate both easily (and the same stands for `defaultdict`'s), but if you want to compress creation and filling of two `Counter`'s into one statement, you'll need something like

```
from collections import Counter
rnc, sac = map(Counter, 
  zip(*((p.return_number, p.scan_angle) for p in lasfile.File(inFile,None,'r'))))
```

Note that at least on Python 2 it will produce a list, so all data will be held in memory at once at some point.

Yet, the much simpler ways to go are:

- use two `defaultdict`s:

  ```
  returns, angles = defaultdict(int), defaultdict(int)
  for p in lasfile.File(inFile, None, 'r'):
       returns[p.return_number] += 1
       angles[p.scan_angle] += 1
       count += 1
  ```
- or fill two `Counter`s in two different reads of the file:

  ```
  fp = lasfile.File(inFile, None, 'r')
  returns = Counter(p.return_number for p in fp)
  fp = lasfile.File(inFile, None, 'r')
  angles = Counter(p.scan_angle for p in fp)
  ```

Comment: Or if `Counter` is available, `returns = collections.Counter(p.return_number for p in fp)` (where `fp` is the lasfile.File object.)

Comment: @DSM Right... I keep forgetting about `Counter`.

Comment: @DSM: You should post that as an answer; it's about as "code saving" as possible, and pretty elegant, so I think it's exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: @DSM: could i combine Counter? ex: if i wish to count p.return_number and p.scan_angle in the same time

Comment: @Gianni I made a typo, sorry. Edited. Try again please. Unfortunately, I can't test it "as is" here (no idea what las files are :))

Comment: @LevLevitsky don't problem and thanks. I think there is another problem because if i run the line there are always ..., ...,

Comment: @Gianni What do you mean? Where exactly do you see it?

Comment: when i run 
rnc, sac = map(Counter, 
   zip(*((p.return_number, p.scan_angle) for p in lasfile.File(inFile,None,'r'))) i cannot close the line

Comment: @Gianni One last closing `)` was missing... sorry again.

Answer (score 3):

Use a dictionary:

```
return_counts = {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}
count = 0
for p in lasfile.File(inFile,None,'r'):
    count +=1
    if 1 <= p.return_number <= 5:
        return_counts[p.return_number] += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `p.return_number` is in the range 1-5

```
Return = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
for p in lasfile.File(inFile,None,'r'):
    Return[p.return_number-1] += 1
```